# How to get access token of Facebook closed group? (I am one of the admins)

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I want to get all the posts and comments from my Facebook group. 
When I using Facebook API, it needs me to provide access token of this group.
I could get all the text from a public group, but don't know how to get data from private groups.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/group/feed

> The `user_managed_groups` permission can be used to read the group
>   content for a group in which the user is an admin

Of course you need a User Access Token for that.

Comment: you´re welcome. please don´t forget to accept my answer ;)